Taking partial derivatives with dependent variables
When dealing with multivariate calculus e.g. a $f$ s.t.
$f = f(x,y,z,w)$
and $x,y$ are really not independent variables but depend on $z$ and $w$. See this for a good example.
we can calculate partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t. $x$ viewed in two different ways:

$x$ considered independent of $z, w$
we take into account the dependence of $x$ on $z$ and $w$

The linked answer shows the two cases.
My question is, is doing 1. ever correct? (e.g., when solving a problem in physics). With 1, I can get any result I want. I mean I can have a complicated expression and I can invent new variables for things I don't know how to differentiate etc. and get a simple expression for $\partial f / \partial x$.
To restate the question in another form, when we have a function of $n$ multiple variables, does it ever make sense to disguise or view it as a function of $m > n$ variables with some variables dependent on others but the dependence effectively ignored in taking partial derivatives?

By the chain rule ignoring the dependence is equivalent to assuming that the quantity is constant with respect to the other, i.e., not including a term in the derivative is equivalent to multiplying that term by zero.

I am honestly not sure what’s tricking you up, but I’m going to try anyway.
When we deal with the functions and say that, say, $f=f(x,y,z)$, it already implies the independence of the variables used.
Whenever you say your variable $x$ is not independent but rather a function of the two other variables, $x=x(w, z)$, you implicitly make the case of, in fact, a different function which doesn’t contain that $x$ per se. A simple example would do the explanation.
Imagine you have a function:
$$
f(x,y,z) = x^3 + 2y - 3z
$$
Here, you can take all the partial derivatives you want, i. e., with respect to any variables, and that is rather clear.
Imagine now, that you say that $x$ is now a dependent variable and, in fact, a function of the two others, namely $x=y^2-z^3$.
Once you define that new function $f=f(y^2-z^3, y, z)$, it is not at all a function of $x$ anymore, and it makes no use to try and define an operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.
